# How to change array layout?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

What is the efficient way to convert the following numpy arrays:

```
a1 = \
[[ 1.1 -1.1  0.1]
 [ 2.1 -2.1  0.1]
 [ 3.1 -3.1  0.1]
 [ 4.1 -4.1  0.1]
 [ 5.1 -5.1  0.1]]
```

and

```
a2 = \
[[ 1.2 -1.2  0.2]
 [ 2.2 -2.2  0.2]
 [ 3.2 -3.2  0.2]
 [ 4.2 -4.2  0.2]
 [ 5.2 -5.2  0.2]]
```

into A:

```
[[[ 1.1  1.2]
  [ 2.1  2.2]
  [ 3.1  3.2]
  [ 4.1  4.2]
  [ 5.1  5.2]]
 [[-1.1 -1.2]
  [-2.1 -2.2]
  [-3.1 -3.2]
  [-4.1 -4.2]
  [-5.1 -5.2]]
 [[ 0.1  0.2]
  [ 0.1  0.2]
  [ 0.1  0.2]
  [ 0.1  0.2]
  [ 0.1  0.2]]]
```

Is there a way to do it without copying data (e.g. modifying values in A would also modify corresponding values in a1 or in a2)?

UPD. Here's one of the accepted answers and the way back I have used - as copying is finally mandatory:

```
import numpy as np

a1 = [[ 1.1, -1.1,  0.1],
      [ 2.1, -2.1,  0.1],
      [ 3.1, -3.1,  0.1],
      [ 4.1, -4.1,  0.1],
      [ 5.1, -5.1,  0.1]]
a1 = np.array(a1)

a2 = [[ 1.2, -1.2,  0.2],
      [ 2.2, -2.2,  0.2],
      [ 3.2, -3.2,  0.2],
      [ 4.2, -4.2,  0.2],
      [ 5.2, -5.2,  0.2]]
a2 = np.array(a2)

a_expected = [[[ 1.1,  1.2],
      [ 2.1,  2.2],
      [ 3.1,  3.2],
      [ 4.1,  4.2],
      [ 5.1,  5.2]],
     [[-1.1, -1.2],
      [-2.1, -2.2],
      [-3.1, -3.2],
      [-4.1, -4.2],
      [-5.1, -5.2]],
     [[ 0.1,  0.2],
      [ 0.1,  0.2],
      [ 0.1,  0.2],
      [ 0.1,  0.2],
      [ 0.1,  0.2]]]

npar = 2

a = np.concatenate((a1[...,None].transpose(1,0,2), a2[...,None].transpose(1,0,2)), npar)
assert np.all(a == a_expected)

new_a1 = a.transpose(2, 1, 0)[0]
new_a2 = a.transpose(2, 1, 0)[1]

assert np.all(new_a1 == a1)
assert np.all(new_a2 == a2)
```

Comment: In general, given `a1` and `a2`, there is no way to form `A` without copying. Every NumPy array contains a pointer to the start of a contiguous block of memory. It then uses strides, shape and dtype to locate values in the array. If the underlying data in `a1` and `a2` are not part of one contiguous block of memory, there is no way to join them -- without copying -- into one new NumPy array, `A`, since the new array can have only *one pointer*, one stride, one shape and one dtype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach with [`ndarray.transpose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.transpose.html) and [`np.concatenate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) -

```
np.concatenate((a1[...,None].transpose(1,0,2),a2[...,None].transpose(1,0,2)),2)
```

Another with [`ndarray.T`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.T.html) and `np.concatenate` -

```
np.concatenate((a1.T[...,None],a2.T[...,None]),2)
```

Final compact one with `ndarray.transpose` and [`np.dstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html) -

```
np.dstack((a1,a2)).transpose(1,0,2)
```

Runtime tests -

```
In [63]: a1 = np.random.rand(500,300)
    ...: a2 = np.random.rand(500,300)
    ...: 

In [64]: %timeit np.concatenate((a1[...,None].transpose(1,0,2),a2[...,None].transpose(1,0,2)),2)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.02 ms per loop

In [65]: %timeit np.concatenate((a1.T[...,None],a2.T[...,None]),2)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.03 ms per loop

In [66]: %timeit np.dstack((a1,a2)).transpose(1,0,2)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.05 ms per loop

In [67]: a1 = np.random.rand(5000,3000)
    ...: a2 = np.random.rand(5000,3000)
    ...: 

In [68]: %timeit np.concatenate((a1[...,None].transpose(1,0,2),a2[...,None].transpose(1,0,2)),2)
1 loops, best of 3: 372 ms per loop

In [69]: %timeit np.concatenate((a1.T[...,None],a2.T[...,None]),2)
1 loops, best of 3: 373 ms per loop

In [70]: %timeit np.dstack((a1,a2)).transpose(1,0,2)
1 loops, best of 3: 371 ms per loop
```

It looks like, either one would be a good choice.